# using an iframe within a <form>

Tags: html, iframe

Is it possible to put an `iframe` within a `form` like this?

[image]

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
<form action = "etc">

<iframe>
 <input type="text" name="text1">Input<br>
 <input type="text" name="text1">Input<br>
 <input type="text" name="text1">Input<br>
 <input type="text" name="text1">Input<br>
</iframe>

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

But I suspect this is not the way to do it. Any pointers?

Comment: What is your reasoning for using an iframe? iframe's are used to embed other web pages/elements from another source into your page.

Comment: I am new to iframes - I was trying to find a frame to place the inputs with its own scroll as I have so many inputs. I suspected iframes were not the correct way but can't to find what I should be using.

Comment: Ah ok, so for this you just want to set a fixed height on a div, and then add `oveflow: scroll` to it which will allow the content to be scrolled. Let me see if i can put together a quick demo

Comment: @taxicala beat me to it below. Thats the correct way to do it iframes are a nasty business :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, you want an element with a scroll, try as follows:

HTML:

```
<fieldset id="lotsOfInputs">
 <input type="text" name="text1">Input<br>
 <input type="text" name="text1">Input<br>
 <input type="text" name="text1">Input<br>
 <input type="text" name="text1">Input<br>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
#lotsOfInputs {
    max-height: 200px;
    with: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - easy when you know how. A great help.

Comment: Glad I could help You out :)